Auto expanding formula in google sheets to the length of a dynamic range
Spreedsheet example I am attempting to apply the formula in D1 of TeamRanks,
=arrayformula(TRANSPOSE(INDEX( FILTER( ARRAYFORMULA( IF( VALUE(redt1) = VALUE(TeamRanks!B1), {VALUE(redt1), VALUE(redt2), VALUE(bluet1), VALUE(bluet2), VALUE(RscoreM), VALUE(BscoreM)}, IF( VALUE(redt2) = VALUE(TeamRanks!B1), {VALUE(redt2), VALUE(redt1), VALUE(bluet1), VALUE(bluet2), VALUE(RscoreM), VALUE(BscoreM)}, IF( VALUE(bluet1) = VALUE(TeamRanks!B1), {VALUE(bluet1), VALUE(bluet2), VALUE(redt1), VALUE(redt2), VALUE(BscoreM), VALUE(RscoreM)}, IF( VALUE(bluet2) = VALUE(TeamRanks!B1), {VALUE(bluet2), VALUE(bluet1), VALUE(redt1), VALUE(redt2), VALUE(BscoreM), VALUE(RscoreM)}, {} ) ) ) ) ), ARRAYFORMULA( IF( VALUE(redt1) = VALUE(TeamRanks!B1), 1, IF( VALUE(redt2) = VALUE(TeamRanks!B1), 1, IF( VALUE(bluet1) = VALUE(TeamRanks!B1), 1, IF( VALUE(bluet2) = VALUE(TeamRanks!B1), 1, 0 ) ) ) ) ) = 1 ), , 5) ))

to the rest of the column that it references (B). it works when it is set to just one cell, but it doesn't work when using =arrayformula to the rest of the column past cell B1.
I have tried arrayformula and array_constrain. Past that I don't know why its not working.
I am hoping that someone has a solution that is a in cell formula, and not an apps script.

Is your current result for 1 row correct? You can simplify the formula using MAP() function I assume.

It looks like the logic of the formula is broken. Please [edit] the question and explain what you want to do instead of explaining the formula that does not do what you want to do. In the sample spreadsheet, show your manually entered desired results instead of showing incorrect formula results. See What is the XY problem?


You may try:
=map(B1:index(B:B,match(,0/(B:B<>""))),lambda(Λ,torow(byrow(Manipulated!B1:index(Manipulated!E:E,match(,0/(Manipulated!E:E<>""))),lambda(Σ,index(ifs(or(Λ=--choosecols(Σ,1,2)),offset(Σ,,4,,1),or(Λ=--choosecols(Σ,3,4)),offset(Σ,,5,,1),1,)))),3)))


